# Include sorting in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I recently added a sorting field and now I want to sort the result. I could do it in PHP or directly on the database. So I tried the second one:

```
SELECT *
FROM constructions
AS whole
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT construction
    FROM data
    AS results
    WHERE product =2
    AND application =1
    AND requirement =1
)
ON whole.id = results
ORDER BY whole.sorting
```

I tried to use inner join to match the complete table with the result set. But I can't get it working (`#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`). I tried to use the alias but something is still wrong. Perhaps I shouldn't user inner join and use `IN()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 obvious errors in the syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM constructions
AS whole
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT construction AS results
    FROM data
    WHERE product =2
    AND application =1
    AND requirement =1
) AS a
ON whole.id = a.results
ORDER BY whole.sorting
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get data like this...

```
 SELECT *
    FROM constructions
    where 
    construction
    in
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT construction
        FROM data
        AS results
        WHERE product =2
        AND application =1
        AND requirement =1
    )
```

Comment: You forgot the `ORDER BY sorting` and the field `construction` is named `id` in my case (but that you can't know). Otherwise it works fine.